# Scraping website with xpath returns nothing

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, xpath, screen-scraping

I'm trying scrape the job positions from the following website: https://supersolid.com/careers.

The data in question is:
[Server Developer, Game Designer/Senior Game Designer, Marketing Artist (2D), Game Designer (New Concepts), Senior Server Developer].

I've tried the usual process of going into developer tools and seeing if there is an XHR file in the network that I could use with all the roles there.
[dev tools / network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGEmz.png)

I then tried to scrape it using XPath

```
    data = []
    url = "https://supersolid.com/careers"
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    xpath = '/html/body/main/section[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/h4'
    jobs = tree.xpath(xpath)
    print(len(jobs))
```

I use `print(len(jobs))` and it returns 0

Not too sure what else I could do.

Comment: When you were in dev tools, did you try to refresh the page and see if it then pops up?

Comment: yeah yeah did all that. the three files as seen in the picture are what I get. nothing useful there. Some font and setting data

Comment: this isn't the issue, but just note, /html/body/main/section[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/h4 would be to the last job. /html/body/main/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/h4 would be the first one. So you'd need it to go to all the h4, which you'll see in Andrej's solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `User-Agent` in HTTP request:

```py
import requests
from lxml import html

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
}
url = "https://supersolid.com/careers"
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
xpath = ".//h4"
jobs = tree.xpath(xpath)
print([j.text for j in jobs])
```

Prints:

```
['Server Developer', 'Game Designer/Senior Game Designer', 'Marketing Artist (2D)', 'Game Designer (New Concepts)', 'Senior Server Developer']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

data = []
url = "https://supersolid.com/careers"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
jobs = soup.find_all('h4')
print(len(jobs))
```